# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type my class C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am getting the data from one of my APIs for language conversion

here is my query

```
var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

the following is my sample data

```
[{"detectedLanguage":{"language":"en","score":1.0},"translations":[{"text":"All","to":"en"},{"text":"सभी","to":"hi"}]}]
```

now I want to convert the data in List

so I created some class as per my data

```
    public class translations
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string to { get; set; }
    }

    public class detectedLanguage
    {
        public string language { get; set; }
        public float score { get; set; }
    }

    public class TranslatedString
    {
        public List<detectedLanguage> detectedLanguage { get; set; }
        public List<translations> translations { get; set; }
    }
```

and use `newtonsoft.Json` to convert this data into list like the following

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
TranslatedString routes_list = (TranslatedString)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
```

but I am getting the error like the following

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'Avalon.TranslatedString'.
```

what can be done to fix this?

Comment: You're not using [tag:json.net] at all, you're using [tag:javascriptserializer].  Which do you mean to use?

Comment: Can there ever be more than one `detectedLanguage`?

Comment: no there wont be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate classes from JSON using this website - [Here](http://json2csharp.com/)

In your case Classes will be -

```
public class DetectedLanguage
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    public double score { get; set; }
}

public class Translation
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public DetectedLanguage detectedLanguage { get; set; }
    public List<Translation> translations { get; set; }
}
```

and code to Deserialize will be -

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I replaced your code, Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Avalon.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.line 1, position 1.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't be doing this in any normal sense `ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`. You are mixing `async` and synchronous code.

Secondly, your json doesn't match with the following

```
"detectedLanguage":{  
     "language":"en",
     "score":1.0
 },
```

and

```
public List<detectedLanguage> detectedLanguage { get; set; }
```

It should be

```
public detectedLanguage detectedLanguage { get; set; }
```

It's a json object not a list.